# Multiple move statements in <FS> in oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have below step in oozie workflow, If both types of source files are present,it works fine. But if only `unfinishedFiles*` files are present.

It does not move these `unfinishedFiles*` files as `finishedFiles*` are not present. It gives `errorcode FS006` for it & does not go ahead & move `unfinishedFiles*` files.

```
<action name="PostMR">
<FS>
<move source='${nameNode}${HADOOP_PATH}/logs/finishedFiles*' target='${nameNode}${HADOOP_PATH}/logs/working'/>
<move source='${nameNode}${HADOOP_PATH}/logs/unfinishedFiles*'     target='${nameNode}${HADOOP_PATH}/logs/working/unfinished'/>
</fs>
<ok to="Pig1"/>
<error to="postMRFS_Error"/>
</action>
```

Can someone help me on this?

**Note:** I don't want to write multiple action because I have many diff files to move.

Answer (score 0):

Oozie executes these commands in sequence as provide in the `fs` action. So if any command fails, it will not execute the further commands.

Comment: [Thank you @YoungHobbit]